# Navigation item not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

so I've been having problems with showing uibarbuttonitem in navigation. 
I am using code:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *confirmButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    confirmButton.title = [@"SETTING_INTRO_CONFIRM" translate];
    confirmButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    confirmButton.target = self;
    confirmButton.action = @selector(confirmSettingsBtnClick:);

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = confirmButton;
```

Adding the button to empty navigation to conform something I selected.
On iOS 9.3 it works fine but on iOS 11 the button is not showing.

The view is showed like this:

```
FirstRunViewController *firstRunViewController = [self getFirstRunViewControllerForActivationContentType:ActivationContentTypeForgottenPasscode];
UINavigationController *firstRunViewControllerWithNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstRunViewController];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [viewController.navigationController presentViewController:firstRunViewControllerWithNavigation animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

If anyone has any idea I would be very happy.

EDIT 1:
The add button code is called in ViewDidLoad of the firstRunViewController. I even tried to put it in viewWill and didAppear but nothing worked.

EDIT 2:
So for testing I tried to check if the button exist with code

```
NSArray *test = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;
```

I called it in viewWillAppear and the button exists, it is just not shown.

EDIT 3: 
So the solution was to change

```
 [viewController.navigationController presentViewController:firstRunViewControllerWithNavigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to:

```
 [self.appDelegate.window setRootViewController:firstRunViewControllerWithNavigation];
```

Comment: Where did you add the item?

Comment: Are you sure `[@"SETTING_INTRO_CONFIRM" translate]` is returning a value? Your code is a little confusing... you instantiate `firstRunViewController`, then call `addLeftNavigationButtonClose` method inside it (which I'm assuming tries to add a `leftBarButtonItem`? But you *then* add it to a Navigation Controller? And are you running your `confirmButton` code in `viewDidLoad()` of `firstRunViewController`? If not, where are you doing that?

Comment: @DonMag I edited the code so that I removed the things that aren't important, and yes the string is returned.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure what's going on. Have you put a `NSLog()` in there to make sure the code is executing? I just did a quick test, and the button is showing up without issue. I put it up as a GitHub repo if you want to take a look and see if anything is odd: https://github.com/DonMag/schmrutest

Comment: Like I already said, it is also weird for me, since on iOS 9.3 it works fine and I know that the code executes.

Comment: The example I put up is working fine on iOS 11. Grab it, and see if it works for you also. If it does, then look for differences between what you're doing and what I did.